# Impossible call function from action module

Tags: nuxt.js, vuex

being used to vuejs, I created a store on nuxt but impossible to succeed in calling a function coming from a module. from what I read, it is necessary that state is a function, thing that I made, but still not possible to call my function, here is how is my store:

store/index.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import user from "./module/user";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
        user,
    },
});
```

store/modules/user.js

```
import Vue from "vue"

export default {
    state = () => ({
        user: null
    }),
    getters: {
        getUser: (state) => state.user
    },
    mutations: {
        INIT_USER(state, data) {
            Vue.set(state, "user", data);
        }
    },
    actions: {
        async initUser({ commit }) {
            try {
                const user = "John"
                await commit("INIT_USER", user);
            } catch (err) {
                console.error(err);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

pages/profile.vue

```
<script>
import { mapActions } from "vuex";

export default {
    methods: {
        ...mapActions(["initUser"]),

        async getUser() {
            this.initUser();
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I have exactly the same code on vuejs (except for the state which is a vuejs object) and it works, so I don't understand the difference with nuxt.

thank you for your help

Comment: Hi, what is not working here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nuxt has its own way of handling Vuex modules, which you should definitely take advantage of. See https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/store/

Briefly, what you want to do is:

- Under your `store` directory, create a file `user.js` and put your store code in it. Nuxt will pick it up automatically and register as a namespaced Vuex module.
- Refactor your store code so it exports each piecce separately, like so:

  ```
    import Vue from "vue"

    export const state = () => ({
        user: null
    }),
    export const getters = {
        getUser: (state) => state.user
    },
    export const mutations = {
        INIT_USER(state, data) {
            Vue.set(state, "user", data);
        }
    },
    export const actions = {
        async initUser({ commit }) {
            try {
                const user = "John"
                await commit("INIT_USER", user);
            } catch (err) {
                console.error(err);
            }
        }
    }
  ```
- In your component - you can use the store as follows:

```
import { mapActions } from "vuex";

export default {
    methods: {
        ...mapActions('user', ['initUser']),

        async getUser() {
            this.initUser();
        }
    }
}
```

Or even like this:

```
<script>
export default {
    methods: {
        getUser() {
            this.$store.dispatch('user/initUser');
        }
    }
}
</script>
```